docker volume ls shows httptoolkit-injected-data-1.15.0 volume
I was just checking if the volumes for a new Docker Compose file were creating the volumes I needed. While running docker volume ls, I found that I have that volume.
I've been looking everywhere to see if this was introduced by Docker or VSCode at some point, but I haven't found any information.
I also ran docker ps -a --filter volume=httptoolkit-injected-data-1.15.0 and so far no container is using that volume.
Does anyone else have it, or does anyone know why it exists?

This means you've used HTTP Toolkit for Docker interception on your machine at some point. The volume is just created for this (it stores various files that need to be temporarily mounted into a target container), and persists just for performance in case that's needed again.
As long as you aren't currently running HTTP Toolkit, you can delete this with no consequence. If you run HTTP Toolkit again and it's required in future it'll just be recreated.
